# Eclipse in OS X uses different version of Java than CLI

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

When I type `java -version` in the console I get `java version "1.8.0_05"`. The soft link `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK` points to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents`. In the java preferences window, the only listed version of Java is 1.8. JAVA_HOME is set to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home`.

However, when I try to run Eclipse.app, I get the error: `Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater required.`

I believe it is trying to use `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and in that directory the only version is `1.6.0.jdk`.

How can I get eclipse to use the correct version of Java?

Comment: change your eclipse.ini to have `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`

Comment: Jigar, all that does is change the error from 1.7 to "Version: 1.8 or greater required"

Comment: what does `java --version` show on new terminal

Comment: java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Download the 64-bit version of Eclipse.

Comment: 64-bit version works. Thank you.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, would you be so kind and post this as an answer?

Comment: @atamanroman Sure. Added some information on why this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download the 64-bit version of Eclipse instead of the 32-bit version.

The reason is that Eclipse contains native machine code (for the GUI) which is why there is both a 32-bit and 64-bit version of Eclipse, and this explicitly require the corresponding Java version.  Originally Apple created both versions up to Java 6, but Oracle only creates a 64-bit version (much to the dismay of owners of older machines). So, if you download a 32-bit version of Eclipse it will only run with an Apple JVM, which apparently is too old (which surprise me - I thought Java 6 was still supported for Eclipse 4.4)

Comment: It appears that for OS X Java 6 is not in the test matrix, only oracle 7+8 (but Java 6 is for all other platforms) http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/readme_eclipse_4.4.php#TargetOperatingEnvironments. Perhaps the 32-bit download should be removed then .

Answer (score 10):

I solved this issue in my mac with yosemite:

1. Installed JDK for MACOSX 64bits from https://jdk8.java.net/download.html
2. Inside the eclipse.ini I put this line:

   > -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

And it worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me and I didn't need to update the eclipse.ini file.  I am using OSX Yomemite 10.10.2

Comment: This worked for me and I didn't do the second step either. I am on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this same problem but rather than making it to use version 1.8 I changed the settings in `eclipse.ini` file so I can just run the program regardless which version of jvm does it want to use

**Solution:**

Open the directory where you have **Eclipse** copy in your computer.

You would see a file name `eclipse` press `control` key and `click` on it to see the options.

Then click on `Show Original`from the options, there you would find `eclipse.ini` file open it with a text editor and change the `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7` to `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6`

Save the file and open the `ecplise.app` it should open now without any error

Comment: mine was set to 1.6 when I opened it :(

Comment: @Jackson are you still having this problem even though it's 1.6 there?

Comment: Yes. I have a project due tomorrow so I had to switch back to Eclipse Juno in order to get things to work. Better luck next time hopefully!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following lines to your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Maybe a newer version of eclipse could help, too (if yours is out of date).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your `System Preferences` -> `Java`. It should open the `Java Control Panel`. In the panel, check if you have one (or many) JDKs.

I suspect you have many and are setting the JDK in your `.profile` while Eclipse is reading some other Java Home.

You can change them manually by running this in your terminal

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

To check if it worked, run `java -version` and you should see something like

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Try calling Eclipse now from the command line. To call Eclipse as an App, just set the Java8 through the `Java Control Panel`. This will be read when Eclipse starts.

This is what I have on my `Java Control Panel`:

[image]

This is on my Eclipse Luna:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Download the 64-bit version of Eclipse.`

This solved the problem. Thanks everyone.

Comment: does not help on windows 8.1