# Error launching Eclipse 4.4 "Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product."

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem launching Eclipse 4.4 on my Mac. I'm getting the following error: 
"Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product." 
I have the latest version installed. When I'm running java -version I'm getting:

```
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here is my eclipse.ini file where I already tried to explicit set the -vm parameter to my jdk1.8:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-vm 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: Install; http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html That fix my problem.

Comment: Above one helped me too. `OSX 10.9.5`

Comment: Above one helped me too. Thanks @Can Ürek

Comment: Above one helped me too. Windows 7. Thanks a lot @ca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you got the x64 edition of eclipse. Someone answered this just [a few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598465/eclipse-in-os-x-uses-different-version-of-java-than-cli/).

Comment: If this doesn't work (it didn't for me) installing the Java Development Kit (NB Not the JRE) from Oracle as suggested by the other answer is recommended.

Answer (score 74):

Here's how to fix this error when launching Eclipse:

> Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.7 or greater is required.

1. Go and install [latest JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Make sure you have installed 64 bit Eclipse

Comment: I already had the x64 edition of eclipse. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: This was the key bit for me: "Install appropriate Java SE Development Kit".  (This is also known as the JDK, and is not to be confused with the smaller-sized Java Runtime Environment, or JRE). Thank you!

Comment: This has solved the problem!

Answer (score 10):

Your -vm argument seems ok BUT it's position is wrong. According to this [Eclipse Wiki entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) :

> The -vm option must occur before the -vmargs option, since everything after -vmargs is passed directly to the JVM.

So your -vm argument is not taken into account and it fails over to your default java installation, which is probably 1.6.0_65.

Comment: That solved the problem for me - I added `-vm` option with path to java to `eclipse.ini` before --`launcher.appendVmargs` and it worked like a charm. My problem was the same and I had 64bit Eclipse, but it's fixed now :)

Comment: This should be the right answer