# JVM on Eclipse. not working?

Tags: eclipse, jvm

I downloaded the newest version of Eclipse and whenever I try and run it this message pops up
"Version 1.6.0_20 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.7 or greater is required"

I went to download JAVA from oracle but it still does it.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: Is JAVA_HOME pointing to Java 1.7?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600860/error-launching-eclipse-4-4-version-1-6-0-65-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-thi?rq=1

Comment: What kind of operating system are you using? On Linux you can switch between default Java versions via standard tools (`update-alternatives`), on Windows newer Java replaces older Java (`java` executable is placed in `System32`). The most painful it is on OSX, where you have to set `JAVA_HOME` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check JAVA_HOME path is set to something like C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin; till bin. not sure but also check Path variable. and have latest JDK installed.