# Eclipse says my java is outdated, but it's not

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

Java.com says I have the current version

Congratulations!
You have the recommended Java installed (**Version 8 Update 25**).

When I try to open Eclipse, it says:

> Version 1.6.0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version:
>   1.7 or greater is required.

I'm running `OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 (Glorified VTech computer)`

Please help me someone, I'm losing my mind completely trying just to run Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: Open up Terminal and type `java -version`. What does it say?

Comment: Please check notes on eclipse.ini .. https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Eclipse was right. How do I get 1.7?

Comment: Go to System Preferences app, click Java at bottom, go to update tab, enjoy life.

Comment: check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598465/eclipse-in-os-x-uses-different-version-of-java-than-cli/

Comment: Java is up to date in system prefs. Also I did download the 64-bit Eclipse twice just to be sure

Comment: Have you checked vm in eclipse.ini file?

Comment: java control panel says product: 1.8.0_25

Answer (score 2):

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/792447/

You can install an older version of java... and reference it in your project. Or like the answer above me states change your java environment to 1.7.

To do this go to Project -> Properties a new window will pop up, and click on java compiler on the left hand window, and then choose your compliance level. I hope this helps

Comment: I can't open Eclipse!

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/792447/
This will help solve your problem. Also this question has been answered before. So please make sure you check before you post a question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have 2 jdk/jre installed in your machine,
and JAVA_HOME environment variable has been set to the older one.

so check the value of the JAVA_HOME, and change it if it's set to the old jre.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you might have 2 (or more) JDK versions on your machine. Sometimes Eclipse just defaults to one outdated version even if you have a newer one.

On Eclipse, go to Run -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs, make sure you have your latest JDK/JRE path on there and change it as default JRE. If your project still refuses to run, go to Run -> Run Configurations, double click on Java Application, under JRE panel, make sure you are using the latest JRE.

I hope this helps.