# Eclipse Oxygen JVM Error

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, eclipse-oxygen

I'm just getting back to java, and went and downloaded the latest Eclipse Oxygen. Once it's all installed, I try to launch and get the following error dialogue.

[image: Incompatible JVM]

So I went and downloaded Java 8 and installed that. Once again I tried to open Eclipse. It still displays the exact same answer. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Uninstall every version of Java on your machine, and download the correct version from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse in OS X uses different version of Java than CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598465/eclipse-in-os-x-uses-different-version-of-java-than-cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On macOS you must install the full JDK - the JRE install isn't enough.

Get the full JDK from the Oracle site [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

If you install Java 9 you will need to use at least Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) but preferably the current Eclipse, for eariler versions of Eclipse install Java 8.